# Transfer token automate

Tags: solidity

I'm new to solidity I need to transfer my token(ERC20) to a list of specified addresses.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.19;
import "./BorgiasCapitalFundToken.sol";


contract SendBCF {
    BorgiasCapitalFundToken public borgiasCapitalFundToken;

    struct OldToken {
        uint256 value;
        address member;
    }

    OldToken[] public oldTokenList;

    address public owner;

    function SendBCF(address contractAddress) public {
        borgiasCapitalFundToken = BorgiasCapitalFundToken(contractAddress);
        oldTokenList.push(OldToken({ value: 440000000, member: 0x54C340CcD7C35753F6BC638f2eDA9f9443D08876}));
        owner = msg.sender;      
    }

    function finalSend() public {
        for (uint i = 0; i < oldTokenList.length; i++) {
            borgiasCapitalFundToken.transfer(oldTokenList[i].member, oldTokenList[i].value);
        }
    }
}
```

However, i'm getting a revert whenever finalSend is called. What is the correct implementation of this?

Comment: I'm guessing you run out of gas. What's the error message?

Comment: warning: error encountered during contract execution [reverted]. Out of gas happens if there are more than 100 items in that list.

Comment: when i call the transfer, where do the tokens go from.. who is the msg.sender ?

Comment: I don't see any use for the `msg.sender` except `owner` which is also useless. But in token transfers the tokens are always transferred from one owner to another and the actual information about the owner is just stored inside the token contract.